# on the click of the row in table ,i want to hide the below tr tags

Tags: jquery, html

The issue I am facing is this suppose there are 3 child row,then with my code its 
removing only one row.
I want to toggle all the child rows.

Row 1
.vineet 1
.vineet 2
.vineet 3 
Row 2
.hrithik 1
.hrithik 2
.hrithik 3
Row 3
.srk 1
.srk 2
.srk 3
So, if i click on Row 1,its removing 'vineet 1' only, i want to remove 'vineet 2','vineet 3' also.

Similarly if i click on Row 2,it should remove hrithik 1, hrithik 2,hrithik 3,all 3.

Similarly for Row3.

> Code:

```js
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function() {
  j$('[Id$=uppertrId]').click(function() {
    alert('Hii');
    j$(this).next("tr").toggle();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<apex:form>
  <apex:pageblock>
    <apex:slds />
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered" id="myTable">

      <head>
        <tr id="trid">
          <td id="tabid">
            <p>Name</p>
          </td>
          <td id="tabid">
            <p>Industry</p>
          </td>
          <td id="tabid">
            <p>Phone</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </head>

      <body>
        <apex:repeat value="{!wraplst}" var="wrap">
          <tr id="uppertrId">
            <td class="fname" id="nameid">>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!wrap.acc.name}</td>
            <td>{!wrap.acc.Industry}</td>
            <td>{!wrap.acc.Phone}</td>
          </tr>
          <apex:repeat value="{!wrap.conlst}" var="cont">
            <tr id="lowerId">
              <td class="lname" id="lowertdId">{!cont.Lastname}</td>
              <td>{!cont.Email}</td>
              <td>{!cont.Phone}</td>
            </tr>
          </apex:repeat>
        </apex:repeat>
      </body>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It hides all the rows except from the clicked one

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('tr').toggle();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>Hey</thead>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi. Tnx for the response. The above code is removing the complete table except the clicked row. I want rest of the table to be there.

Comment: Like there are 10 other rows also apart from row 1. its like tree view structure

Comment: It is hiding just the rows. I have added a header to the table just for reference. Check the edits

Comment: can you update the question with the structure you are talking about, because in the present code i cannot see any structure other then 3 td inside a row.

Comment: actually ur solution works perfectly fine with the clicked row,but in addition to that it also toggles the other rows. Like there are row 1,row 2,row 3. if i use your code and click on row 2,it works fine,but at the same time it toggles the row1,and row3 also, which i dont want

Comment: no ...i think previous one was good. here also it is working for all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using next use  $(this).nextAll("tr").toggle();

Comment: Thnx for response. your code actually removes everything below the clicked row. I need to remove the child rows. like the 3 row which contains vineet 1, vineet 2, vineet 3,simultaneously.

Comment: you want to remove the current row in which user click ?

Comment: I want to remove the child elements of the specific row clicked. Like if i click the Row 1 ,then the child elements vineet 1,vineet 2,vineet 3 will be removed . But nothing should happen to the child of the Row 2,Row 3

Comment: if you mean child inside row that is all td inside tr which means a whole row $(this).toggle(); try this or please send the actual html for proper response

Comment: Do you know accordian view,chevron up and down. the tree view structure that kind of thing i need

Comment: $(this).children().toggle(); please check with this my final solution :D

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this with the help of *.not()* jquery filter**

For Example

```
function removerow(){$("tr").not(".nothide").toggle();}
```

```
<thead>
  <tr class="nothide">
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="nothide" onclick="removerow();">
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>vineet 1</td>
  </tr>
   <tr class="hide">
    <td>vineet 2</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>vineet 3</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: you were very close to it but it is hiding the child rows of evry parent row. like after writing your code, I can see only 3 rows left Row 1,Row 2,Row3.

Comment: i want to hide the child rows of the row clicked .

Comment: are you want to insert another row inside row please tell me clear

Comment: no..no.Its actually show hide. Like if i click Row1,then Vineet1,vineet2,vineet3 will toggle and it will not affect Row2,Row3.

Comment: Sorry, I apologize for the misunderstanding, as I understand for example if you click on row 1 then the only action applies on row 1 data, not other rows.